# Re-using CLI installation in a multi-stage docker file

Tags: docker

I am writing a multi-stage Dockerfile. The first step is to install a cli:

```
FROM python:3 as cfngenerate

RUN pip install cloudformation-cli
```

The second step is to build a Java project with maven. This build relies on the CLI above.

```
FROM maven as build

COPY --from=cfngenerate /usr/local/bin/cfn /usr/local/bin/cfn

RUN mvn package
```

This however doesn't work. The Maven step fails with: `java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cfn-cli": error=2, No such file or directory`

How can I ensure that the CLI is available in the second step?

I think the more general question is, how do I have one step rely on two frameworks (Maven and a python CLI)?

Comment: Your `mvn package` needs a `cfn-cli` executable, but you copied `cfn`. Isn't there any `cfn-cli` to copy to the other stage?

Comment: @AliTou Yes, copied that too, and the Python installation. Now I get `/usr/local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: It says that it needs a missing shared library and the copied executable is not enough for that program to start (It needs probably more than this one shared library. Thus copying all of them doesn't worth it). I think the multi-stage approach here doesn't work. I suggest the recommendations in answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 "FROM" means two separate images. If you need both frameworks, there are few options

1. Use base docker images, then install python and maven
2. Use python image, then install maven. You need to do required setup for maven.
3. Use maven image, then install python. You need to do required setup for python.
4. Look for an image which already install python and maven, shared by others. (eg. https://hub.docker.com/r/openkbs/jre-mvn-py3). It might included unnecessary things you don't need.

Comment: Ended up using #3. Thanks for the help :)